# How to split list of lists based on the repetitivity of the value of the lists?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of lists in this format that represents coordinates:

```
[['1', '1'], 
 ['2', '2'], 
 ['3', '3'], 
 ['1', '1'], 
 ['5', '5'], 
 ['6', '6'], 
 ['7', '7'], 
 ['5', '5'], 
 ['8', '8'], 
 ['9', '9'], 
 ['10', '10'], 
 ['8', '8']]
```

I want to split this list of lists into 3 lists of lists so that the first lists starts with the list `[1, 1]` and ends with the list `[1, 1]`, the 2nd starts with the list `[5, 5]` and ends with the list `[5, 5]`, etc.

So basically, I want to create a new list each time the same value as the initial value of the list is encountered.

Any idea on how I can achieve such operation?

**Edit.** some tries I've explored but didn't get the expected results:

```
poly_pts = []
for pt in tlist:
    x = 0
    init_pt = tlist[0]
    if pt != init_pt:
        poly_pts.append(pt)
        x += 1
    elif pt == init_pt:
        poly_pts.append(pt)
        init_pt = tlist[x+1]
```

#

```
all_lists = []
init_pt = tlist[0]        
for pt_i, pt in enumerate(tlist):
    if pt == init_pt and pt_i != tlist.index(init_pt):
        all_lists.append(tlist[tlist.index(init_pt):pt_i+1])
```

Comment: This will be very easy with a for loop.  Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I've been tring for 1 hour but I need some ideas to help me. That is why I posted. Thanks for your precious help here...

Comment: If you've tried for 1 hour then you should have some failed attempts to demonstrate, that we can help you with improving.  Questions are usually well-received here when they show some effort.

Comment: Edited the main post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
t = [['1', '1'], 
 ['2', '2'], 
 ['3', '3'], 
 ['1', '1'], 
 ['5', '5'], 
 ['6', '6'], 
 ['7', '7'], 
 ['5', '5'], 
 ['8', '8'], 
 ['9', '9'], 
 ['10', '10'], 
 ['8', '8']]


ix = 0
tmp = []

while ix < len(t):
   tmp.append(t[ix:t.index(t[ix], ix+1)+1])
   ix = t.index(t[ix], ix+1) + 1


>>> tmp
[[['1', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['3', '3'], ['1', '1']], [['5', '5'], ['6', '6'], ['7', '7'], ['5', '5']], [['8', '8'], ['9', '9'], ['10', '10'], ['8', '8']]]
```

I don't check any error, it's up to you to implement that. I'm using `[].index`, which give the index of an element in a list, this function can also take a second parameter to specify from which index you want to search the element.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
first = []
all_lists = []
j = 0
for i, item in enumerate(a):
    if first == []:
        first = a[i]
        print(first)
    elif first == a[i]:
        all_lists.append(a[j:i+1])
        j = i + 1
        first = []
print(all_lists)
```

Its similar to your first attempt, but i use enumerate() to give me an tuple of index and item. The trick is to reassert first (like init_pt in your code) to be empty after finding a match.

Answer (score 0):

`list.index()` gives the index of element where the element first occurs in the list

```
temp =[]
while True:
    try:
        idx = list[1:].index(list[0])
    except ValueError:
        temp.append(list)
        break
    if idx == len(list)-2:
        temp.append(list)
        break
    temp.append(list[:idx+2])
    list = list[idx+2:]
```

what essentially is happening in the above code is

inside the `try` we are trying to get the index of first element of the list in rest of the list except the firs element. If there is no element in rest of list it raises `ValueError` and ends the loop

If we get the index of element then for example if there are 5 elements in list like `list=[1,2,3,4,1]`

`idx = 3` so if `idx+2 = len(list)` then that will be the end of the loop because the no elements will be left after this part of list.

Else the loop continues slicing the list until one of above two conditions occur

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.